# redirect in PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, redirect, contact-form

I have build a PHP contact form on wordpress that redirects user based upon his/her selected region.

I have used 'www.google.com' as a test URL.

However, the form is getting redirected to the custom theme page that I built on WP instead.

Where am I going wrong?

Please find the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Meal Planner </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    function checkregion($Region)
    {
        SWITCH ($Region) {
            case "North":
                header('location:https://www.google.com/');
                break;
            case "South":
                header('location:https://www.google.com/');
                break;
            case "East":
                header('location:https://www.google.com/');
                break;
            case "West":
                header('location: https://www.google.com/');
                break;
        }
    }

    checkregion($Region);
    ?>
        <form action="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/custompage1.php " method="POST">
            <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
            <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
            <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
            <p>Dropdown Box</p>
            <select name="Region" size="1">
                <option value="North">North</option>
                <option value="South">South</option>
                <option value="East">East</option>
                <option value="West">West</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"><input type="reset" value="CLEAR">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$Region` is not set when you call `checkregion($Region);`.

Comment: Used WordPress nonces to retrieve your form values (https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/introduction-to-wordpress-nonces-5357)

Answer (score 0):

To call your `checkRegion` function on the same page as the form then unless this page is `customepage1.php` you need to remove the action from the form and pass the POST variable `Region` as the input parameter to your function. As you are calling `header` function you should invoke this function before any HTML content has been generated ( unless you have `output buffering` enabled )

```
<?php

    function checkregion( $Region ) {
        switch ($Region) {
            case 'North': header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); break;
            case 'South': header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); break;
            case 'East': header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); break;
            case 'West': header('Location: https://www.google.com/'); break;
        }
    }
    if( !empty( $_POST['Region'] ) ) checkregion( $_POST['Region'] );
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Meal Planner </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>

            <p>Name</p> <input type='text' name='name'>
            <p>Email</p> <input type='text' name='email'>
            <p>Phone</p> <input type='text' name='phone'>
            <p>Dropdown Box</p>

            <select name='Region' size='1'>
                <option value='North'>North
                <option value='South'>South
                <option value='East'>East
                <option value='West'>West
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'><input type='reset' value='CLEAR'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, when I am applying this code, I am getting 404 error.

Comment: did it help or still having issues?

Comment: still having issues..getting page not found error...is it because the way the header function is called...do i need to rework on the synatx?

Comment: are you saying it can't find google or another url, as yet, undisclosed to us?

Comment: I have just tested exactly what I posted above and it works fine. Note that I did make a change above as I had forgotten to use `$_POST['Region']` as the parameter to the `checkregion` function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $region = $_POST['Region'];
       switch ($region ) {
            case 'North': $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
            case 'South': $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
            case 'East':  $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
            case 'West':  $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
        }
     if(!empty($url)){
       header('Location: '+ $url);
     }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Meal Planner </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">

            <p>Name</p> <input type='text' name='name'>
            <p>Email</p> <input type='text' name='email'>
            <p>Phone</p> <input type='text' name='phone'>
            <p>Dropdown Box</p>

            <select name='Region' size='1'>
                <option value='North'>North
                <option value='South'>South
                <option value='East'>East
                <option value='West'>West
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type='submit' name="submit" value='SUBMIT'><input type='reset' value='CLEAR'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi...however i am getting a 404 error with the same code....is it because I am using it in wordpress? you can check it here: https://mydailysugar.info/meal-tester-page/

Comment: try rename name fields to `name='contact-name'`  `name='contact-email'` `name='contact-phone'`

source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11749/why-when-i-submit-a-form-in-wordpress-it-loads-a-404-page-though-url-is-correct

Comment: Hi, i did...now instead of giving 404 error, it is staying on the same page. check: https://mydailysugar.info/meal-tester-page/